# Stop loading objects over long distances in Three JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphics, three.js, 3d

I am developing a project in Three JS for my company, which involves the visualization of a 3D map with real objects loaded.

Due to performance reasons, I would like to stop loading/viewing objects that are far from the current cursor/user position, so the program can be faster and more efficient.

Is there any way to do this?

[image: For the more curious, here is an overview of the current project, under development.]

Comment: For that you’ll need to use Threejs LOD https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/LOD. But just curiosity what maps engine are you using?

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot. :)
The map it's a geojson!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Just FYI I develop an open source Three js plug-in using Mapbox as an engine, and the performance is quite good as most of the map work (and the red building boxes in your picture) is done by Mapbox and Three js is only used to represent complex models (like the bridge in your picture). Here is the link if you want to check it out https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox. I’m planning LOD for the next release